# Rounded corners for buttons using three images and css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I'm looking for a way to use three images as background urls in css to create links/buttons with rounded corners. There is an image on the left that has rounded corners for the top left and bottom left, an image in the middle that is repeatable, and an image on the right that has rounded corners for the top right and bottom right.

Ideally, the code can work for both links and buttons, and ideally I don't need to specify the width for each link or button. If possible, the width would be the width of the text and some margin or the width of the button.

Is this possible for Internet Explorer 7-9, and the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari?

Comment: The images I'm working with are much like this: http://h.imagehost.org/0484/1_87.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can define three div and define the properties as like this

You can define images in background replace to color .

**CSS**

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
}

.left, .middle, .right{
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

.left{
    background:yellow url(../..) no-repeat ;
}

.middle{
    background:red url(../..) repeat-x;
    width:auto;
    line-height:100px;
}

.right{
    background:green url(../..) no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="">
<span class="left"></span>
<span class="middle">Heere you text </span>
<span class="right"></span>
</a>
​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/HAjLZ/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pre-split the background image. Have a look at the button on this page: http://easyhanzi.com/

This is done using only one image that is split using CSS. Then there are three DIVs - one left, one center and one right. The content can have any width.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="download-button">
    <div id="download-button-left"></div>
    <div id="download-button-middle">
        <center><div id="download-button-main-text">Download free trial</div><div id="download-button-subtext">Version 3.1 for Windows</div></center>
    </div> <!-- download-button-middle -->
    <div id="download-button-right"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#download-button-left {
    float: left;
    background: url(img/download-button.png) 0 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 85px;
}

#download-button-middle {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;

    float: left;
    background: url(img/download-button.png) -12px 0;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 70px;
}

#download-button-right {
    float: left;
    background: url(img/download-button.png) -399px 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 85px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery mobile for this horizontal grouped buttons shown in this link----> [Grouped Buttons](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html)